# Need a recursive version of the Euclid's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have a task where I have the algorithm of Euclid and need to make a recursive version of it. I can't really get what the recursive version of an algorithm is actually, so any help here would be very appreciated! :)

The given algorithm is:

```
X ← MAX
Y ← MIN
while (Y != 0){
     mod ← X mod Y
     X ← Y
     Y ← mod}
GCD ← X
```

Comment: You need to show some effort by writing it in some programming language and then retag your question and somebody might answer.

Comment: Recursion can be seen as a looping mechanism. Thus, think about how the `while` loop with a condition could be converted to a recursive call with a base case.

Comment: this is [recursion](https://www.google.com/#q=recursion) ;)

Comment: Type *recursive euclid algorithm* into Google and start reading. The Wikipedia article has an implementation.

Comment: Addressing the first comment, the algorithm in my book is given in pseudo language and not in a programming one ( I don't know what it's called in English) and since it was in Greek, I tried my best to translate it. To everyone else,thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The recursion is actually very similar to the iterative

```
GCD(X,Y):
  if Y == 0:
    return X
  else:
    return GCD(Y, X mod Y)
```

Comment: If `Y == 0` wouldn't you return `X`?  Seems like this will only ever return 0 since your condition to terminate the recursion is the `Y == 0 return 0`.

Comment: Thanks man, I understand now what it wanted me to do all along. Couldn't really get what recursion was and how it was implemented. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume X >= Y > 0,

Essentially the recursion is solving the problem with a smaller X' and Y' until the answer is obvious(Here X' = Y and Y' = X % Y).

The recursive version algorithm of Euclid for solving Greatest Common Divisor(GCD) is (C version) :

```
int GCD(X, Y)
{
    if ((X % Y) == 0)
    {
        return Y; 
    }
    else
    {
        return GCD(Y, X % Y);
    }
}
```